# Combine a group of shapes into an image

Tags: svg

Given an image composed entirely of different shapes that do not move and are grouped together, how would I convert this group into an image or similar element that has this same graphic but all together? The reason I'd like them combined is for better performance, because I assume once I get a lot of these shape-based graphics on the screen the frame rate will drop exponentially.

On a similar note: could groups with effects (such as outlines and shadows) applied to them also be merged into a flat graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [buffered-rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#BufferedRenderingProperty) property in SVG Tiny 1.2, it provides what you are after more or less. You set `buffered-rendering="static"` on the <g> element to give the browser the hint that it's good to cache the results.

Of the current generation of browsers only [Opera](http://www.opera.com) supports this property AFAIK.

Yes, effects are included in the "flat graphic", the end result should look exactly the same as if buffered-rendering wasn't there.