# Large SVG / Raphael circle distorts when being animated

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am animating a circle using Raphael.  When the circle is large I get artifacts around the circle when its moving.  It seems to be something of a clipping / redraw region issue and wondered if there was a work around?

It seems to be OK in firefox (if a little jerky) and appears very reliably in Chrome. It also is exacerbated by using opacity on the fill property i.e. `rgba(255,0,0,0.7)`

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHRUT/3/) showing the issue. Just click around the paper on the right to move the circle.

Code:

```
var discattr = {
    fill: "#666",
    stroke: "none",
    width: 35
};

var paper = Raphael("svgcontainer", 400, 400);

circle = paper.circle(150, 150, discattr.width, discattr.width).attr({
    stroke: "none",
    fill: "rgba(255,0,0,0.7)"
});

var coords = []

var animateCircle = function(coords) {
   if (!coords.length) return;
   var nextCoords = coords.shift()
   var move = Raphael.animation(nextCoords, 500, "linear", function() {animateCircle(coords)});
   circle.animate(move);
}    

$("#svgcontainer").on("mouseup", function(e) {
    coords.push({cx: e.pageX, cy: e.pageY})

    animateCircle(coords);
});
```

Comment: I think what you're experiencing is [tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing).

Answer (score 1):

Buffering is a technique used to prevent animation artifacts (tearing, as JamWaffles points out). If you look at the answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498558/combine-a-group-of-shapes-into-an-image) you'll find information about an SVG setting to turn on buffering, but so far it doesn't appear to be supported by major browsers.